# Como usar la libreria WMPLib en VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hola estoy intentando usar la libreria WMPLib, pero no puedo utilizarla.
Compilo mi proyecto, y siempre me devuelve el mismo error:

Foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluí la librería mediante:

```
Imports WMPLib
Dim Player As WindowsMediaPlayer = New WindowsMediaPlayer
```

Pienso que sea a lo mejor la dll, que tenga que probar con otra, por lo que me puse a buscar pero no la encuentro. Alguien sabe como puedo usar esta librería para poner sonido en las aplicaciones?

Error:

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Error   BC30002 No está definido el tipo 'WindowsMediaPlayer'.  C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Scratch-master\Scratch-master\\Form1.vb   7   Activa
```

Comment: Prueba una cosa pon la ruta de la libreria en el path del sistema a ver si sigue dando el mismo error, intenta añadir la libreria al linker de compilación, si compila, cuando ejecutes quita la libreria del path del sistema otra vez y mira a ver si no da error.

Comment: Verificando me di cuenta que no reconoce, 'WindowsMediaPlayer' por lo que actualice el post.

Answer (score 0):

La as de Agregar por Referencia al Proyecto e Importar-la a tu proyecto y eso se hace a través del menú "Proyecto" / "Agregar Referencia"
Una vez allí esta en las librerias COM, Casí al final de la lista 
Agrega la Librería WMP y las adjuntas.

Después de esto se te agregara un nuevo control de usuario que es el WMP